# How to get the Order date from the order id in magento 2

Tags: magento2.2.2, order-details

I wish to get the order date  from order id, to display in the success page. Please provide me a solution

Comment: Do you want to Order details by order id or increment id?

Answer (score 4):

Please used

```
$order->getCreatedAt();
```

you get created date.

Answer (score 0):

Here is ready made free extension,Please check this link

https://github.com/navinbhudiya/magento2-order-details-on-success-page

Answer (score 0):

You can directly get order detail in phtml by object manager

**Note :** You can not use directly object Manager, Second solution is as per Magento standard

**First solution**

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$order = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load($orderId);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($order->getCreatedAt());
exit;
```

**Second Solution**
Get order details by below code

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory $orderFactory
) {
    $this->_orderFactory = $orderFactory;
}

$order = $this->_orderFactory->create()->load($passOrderId);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($order->getCreatedAt());
exit;
```